# Use Android Camera without surface View

Tags: android

I'm developing on android, i want to do somethings with camera (process pixels's values), but just in background, is it possible to do it without surface view? just use a buffer to read pixels's values and do processing.
thanks for every one can help me

Answer (score 6):

As of API-Level 11 the [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) was added. With it a SurfaceView is no longer needed. I tested the following code with my Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo.

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
try {
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Log.e(Version.APP_ID, e1.getMessage());
}

Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.startPreview();
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(Version.APP_ID, "picture-taken");
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `10` in `new SurfaceTexture(10)`? Can we use any number? Is `10` special? Did you generate a texture with that ID before, as the documentation commands? Is this better than using a `SurfaceView`?

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while. I found it there, copied here for convenience.

http://handycodeworks.com/?p=19

Basically, let's just create a dummy SurfaceView (it works even inside a Service), and use it for Camera functions.

```
SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
c.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
c.startPreview();
c.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallback, jpegPictureCallback);
```

Comment: What devices does this work for?  All devices I have tested that use this code result in a "E/CameraHAL(132): Error while configuring rotation"

Comment: Tested on: Galaxy i5800 (2.2), HTC Wildfire (2.1?) - it was a while ago :)

Comment: I did some more research, apparently Samsung is a real stickler about this one, and my testing equipment is all Samsung...

Comment: It definitely *still* works on Samsung Galaxy i5800 - just tested an special purpose app where I had to use this feature.

Comment: Oh, well that's cool.  The notes I read were that Samsung was normally the sticking point.  My Galaxy Nexus isn't handling it.  Android-Segmentation ftl.