# Android: onPreviewFrame never called without SurfaceView

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, preview

On some devices, `onPreviewFrame` is not called if no `SurfaceView` was set to display the camera preview.
However, I handle the camera in a service, so I can't set a `SurfaceView` but I don't want to have visible preview anyway.

How can this be done? Can I programmatically create a `SurfaceView` and set it with `Camera::setPreviewDisplay`?

This must be possible or not?

It works on almost every phone without a `SurfaceView` but not on HTC One X and Google Nexus One...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788993/use-android-camera-without-surface-view), creating a `SurfaceView` in code works fine. Though I don't think you can create it through a service.

Another approach is to create a 1px-1px `SurfaceView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and hiding it with some other view on top of it. (visibility should still be `VISIBLE`). We use this trick for [Path](http://bit.ly/wT3Vpr) camera UI where we render preview buffers through OpenGL and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation readily configured, visible  and displayed surface view is necessary to activate camera preview. It may be overlayued though

Answer (score 0):

From API 11 on, you can use a `SurfaceTexture` instead of a `SurfaceView` to get frames from the camera. Then, instead of using `Camera.setPreviewDisplay`, simply use `Camera.setPreviewTexture`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205661/camera-frames-in-a-service-background-process) answer as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097178/android-camera-in-background?rq=1) discuss this point.