# Android: Add Color Overlay Effects on Video during Capture of Video

Tags: android, video-capture

How to Add Color Overlay Effects on Video during Capture of Video??
Is there any tutorial available? And which library I can use for this??

I have a simple Task to do in this app. On Button click set a color effect on some frames.

My code

```
mCamera = getCameraInstance(); 
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() { 
    @Override 
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
        Log.d("HFI","Length: "+data.length); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manipulate each frame of the video you are capturing/captured. Go have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620560/video-processing-in-android) question and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544877/really-confused-with-setpreviewcallback-in-android-need-advice) question, it should help with your problem.

Comment: While recording `Camera.PreviewCallback` is being not called.

Comment: Is it only being called after recording has taken place?

Comment: No It is not being called ever. My Code: ` mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
   
   @Override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.d("HFI","Length: "+data.length);
   }
  });`

Comment: go have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544877/really-confused-with-setpreviewcallback-in-android-need-advice