# Android OpenCV - How to process camera frames from background service?

Tags: android, opencv

I want to image process android front camera frames inside a service.
I use OpenCV and therefore using CameraBridgeViewBase which asks for camera view.
I dont want to record the video. i need to process each frame in real time.

any solution ?

Comment: That's interesting for me as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JonesV nope. i think its impossible

Comment: I found a solution that I posted below. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the examples of *fadden* available ([have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205661/camera-frames-in-a-service-background-process)), you can do it using a `SurfaceTexture` instead of a `SurfaceView` for getting the frames. It was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097178/android-camera-in-background?rq=1) before, but unfortunately never validated.

I could get frames from a service this way.

Comment: Hi, How could you get frames? onFrameAvailable method returns a surface texture, how did you convert it to fame?