# OpenCV Android: Get camera frames in background without showing on the screen

Tags: android, opencv, camera, background-process

I have written an optic flow detection application which based on OpenCV for Android tutorials and source code of Barry Thomas's application [OpenCV Demo 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=barry.opencvd2&hl=tr). Now I want to make this application a background task so I can pass the detection result to my main activity via listener interface.

All the application samples in OpenCV totorials extends `Activity` and implements `CvCameraViewListener` and shows camera input on the scrren. I want to able to capture camera frames and do optic flow detection on frames in background without showing them on the screen.

How can I get frames from camera in background witout showing camera input?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, but you have to keep a Mat in the memory in the method onCameraFrame:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();      
    return mRgba;
}
```

1) make the cameraview invisible
2) make onCameraFrame return null

Both ways you should do your additional work in another view.

Comment: Making the cameraview invisible stops any processing that happens per frame.. or at least this is what happens in my case

Comment: Making it invisible stops any processing. Returning null results in a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get camera frames in background is by using a `SurfaceTexture` instead of a `SurfaceView`, and therefore set it using `Camera.setPreviewTexture` instead of `Camera.setPreviewDisplay`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205661/camera-frames-in-a-service-background-process) answer as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097178/android-camera-in-background?rq=1) helped.

Comment: You're talking about the Android Camera library, while the question is about OpenCV's library, which uses `org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase`