# Android: taking a picture without calling local Camera app

Tags: android, image, android-camera, capture, android-camera2

I am trying to create a app with which you can take secretly a picture. So my goal is to capture a picture when a button is clicked and then save the taken picture in the gallery without calling the local Camera app.

Thank you for your answer in advance...

Comment: @JordanH I have tried to call the local camera from the device and it worked fine. But my goal is to take secretly a picture on button click without showing any preview etc. I tried to find information about it on the internet but I only found ways which were similar to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to conceal the application then I suggest you to look at this link

[android - use camera without surfaceview or textureview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462360/android-use-camera-without-surfaceview-or-textureview/22468306#22468306).

This shows how to conceal surface textures.